# google calendar credentials handling

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I've built a script that writes to Google Calendar events, I compiled the scripts to one EXE file using Pyinstaller. I've managed to successfully run the file from the source folder, when I try to run it from Desktop it is unable to write to google calendar since it's Credentials file is at source code.

I'm not sure how I can address this issue since I want my friend to be able to use it.

**This is the Calendar script I wrote:**

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import pickle
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from datetime import date, timedelta

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

class PostToGoogleCalendar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.credentials = None
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                self.credentials = pickle.load(token)
        if not self.credentials or not self.credentials.valid:
            if self.credentials and self.credentials.expired and self.credentials.refresh_token:
                self.credentials.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                self.credentials = flow.run_local_server()
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(self.credentials, token)

        self.service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=self.credentials)
        result = self.service.calendarList().list().execute()
        self.calendar_id = result['items'][0]['id']


    def get_events(self):
        current_day_date = date.today()
        this_sunday_date = current_day_date - timedelta(days = (current_day_date.weekday() + 1) % 7)
        sunday_time = '08:00:00.000000Z'
        iso = f'{this_sunday_date}T{sunday_time}'
        events_result = self.service.events().list(calendarId=self.calendar_id, timeMin=iso,
                                                maxResults=500, singleEvents=True,
                                                orderBy='startTime').execute()
        return events_result.get('items', [])

    def create_event(self, event):
        if not self.already_exists(event):
            return self.service.events().insert(calendarId = self.calendar_id, body = event).execute() 
        else:
            return 'Event Already Exists'

    def already_exists(self, event):
        events = self.get_date_events(event['start']['dateTime'], self.get_events())
        event_list = [event['summary'] for event in events]
        if event['summary'] not in event_list:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def get_date_events(self, date, events):
        lst = []
        date = date
        for event in events:
            if event.get('start').get('dateTime'):
                d1 = event['start']['dateTime']
                d1 = d1[:-6]
                if d1 == date:
                    lst.append(event)
        return lst
```

This part is being called from the main script.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may not share your credential file with your friend its against the [TOS](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html) you agreed to with Google when you created your project.

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

Instruct your friend how to create their own credentials file and place in the same directory with your exe so that it can pick it up.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this by default each time a user open my script?
Same way it asks for permission to access each user's google calendar and creates the token?

Comment: No you cant automate creating client credentials.  If you are giving out your code you must also instruct people how to configure it this includes how to create their own client credentials, and verify their application since you are using the full access Google calendar scope they going to have to go though the application verification process as well.  https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: And if i'll change my scope to only events (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events)? Do they still need to create their own credentials? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: As long as you are using Oauth2 to authenticate a user you will need to create a project on Google developer console and create credentials.  You can not share that file.   It doesnt matter what scope you are using.

Comment: Can I authenticate a user without using Oauth2 to avoid this scenario with the credentials?

Comment: In order to access private user data you must have the users permission, in order to get the users permission they must consent to your application accessing their data.  The method used to grant access is called Oauth2.  No you can not access user data without Oauth2.   Why not just give them instructions on how to create their credentials and how to have their app verified?

Comment: I want to avoid having my users create their credentials, I want the app to work with only asking the users permission to write to their calendar. There's no way to do that?

Comment: Host the app some place and have them run it from their, then they are your users.  If you are giving them the source code to run themselves then they need their own credentials.